# Caporali quotes without change font

Tags: punctuation, input-encodings, font-encodings

I've to cite an expression in my text and I would use caporali quotes.

Like this: [image]

I've tried using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but this change my font and I don't like it.
How can I use caporali quotes without change my font?

> text language : italian
>
> utf8 needed

Using `\guillemotleft caporali\guillemotright` without `[T1]` the result is:

[image]

This is not the same quote as first image.

Comment: Please add a mwe, I've tried with this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\guillemotleft caporali\guillemotright
\end{document}` and the caporali seem like the ones in the image for me...

Comment: isn't the same...

Comment: I think a mwe is necessary if you see a difference, look [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to know how to build it.

Comment: update question, but if i use [T1] {fontenc} my font will change and i don't want it. Using [T1] it works

Comment: It's necessary that you add your code, not the result, a little example like the one of my first comment, see the link of my second comment for the instruction on how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with “my font will change”? Does it become jagged? Are you perhaps using MiKTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the caporali quotes of the first image you have to use `T1` fontenc.

If you don't want to use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to the entire document, you can define a single symbol in T1, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}              
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\newcommand{\caporali}[1]{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont «#1»}

\begin{document}

«prova»
\caporali{prova}

\end{document}
```

I think this will not change the font in other part of the document.